# remove duplicate sentences between specified words from string

Tags: c#, string, duplicate-detection

This is my example of some string:

> 1. message: this is some message 2. message: this is some message 3. message: this is message which i want to see only in results

according to this example I would like to get result:

> this is message which i want to see only in results

there might be multiple `x. message:` sentences in my string.

I want to delete those message which are duplicated

any idea?

ADDED:

My question is regarding some selling tool and printing reports. Code I running now looks like this:

```
private void OnBeforePrint(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintEventArgs e) {
    string a = xtraReport1.GetCurrentColumnValue("Paczka_Notatki").ToString();
    xrTableCell3.Text = a;
}
```

when I change it to:

```
private void OnBeforePrint(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintEventArgs e) {
    var str = xtraReport1.GetCurrentColumnValue("Paczka_Notatki").ToString();
    foreach (var message in Regex.Split(str, @"\d+\. message: ")
        .GroupBy(m => m)
        .Where(m => m.Count() == 1 && m.Key != string.Empty)
        .Select(m => new { message = m.Key }))
        {
            xrTableCell3.Text = message.message;
        }
}
```

then I have got a lot of errors like:
[image: error-en]

Comment: Also add your expected output, and your so far approach.

Comment: I have done some research and my environment is Net.Framework 2.0 which does not support used here technology called "LINQ"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String text = xtraReport1.GetCurrentColumnValue("Paczka_Notatki").ToString();

    string finalNote = "";
    string[] notes = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split(text, @"\d{1,}\.\smessage:(?<Message>[\D\s]+)");

    foreach (string note in notes)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(note) && finalNote.IndexOf(note) == -1)
        finalNote += note;
        }
    xrTableCell3.Text = finalNote;
```

thank you guys for support !!!

Answer (score 2):

One way:

```
foreach (var message in Regex.Split(str, @"\d+\. message: ")
    .GroupBy(m => m)
    .Where(m => m.Count() == 1 && m.Key != string.Empty)
    .Select(m => new { message = m.Key }))
{

    Console.WriteLine(message.message);
}
```

Comment: where is the source string variable? "message" or "str" ?

Comment: Its in the `str` variable

Comment: are you sure is it in C#? can you make some online examples of this code?

Comment: @maniootek are you sure you know at least C# 'foreach' expression structure? It seems that you don't know even the simplest things of C#, so you should start from some simpler things while learning the language.

Answer (score 1):

Start from this simple regular expression and you will get your result.

```
\d{1,}\.\smessage:\s(?<Message>[\D\s]+)
```